# How bad is modifying the timer interrupt?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

Suppose we're talking about a cloud linux server.

For a project I have. How bad would it be to modify the timer interrupt such that on each tick the processor will also check 1-4 cached dwords ?

Will that run the system totally unstable? Much slower?

Second, is the timer interrupt is anywhere near the cpu's clock or much slower?
(System_timer, not rtc)

Comment: Second: Much, much, much, *much* slower. Like, several orders of magnitude slower. Timer interrupt intervals can be measured in milliseconds.

Comment: Why would it make the system unstable? If you *know* what you are doing when coding the new part, the system won't be unstable. Cache timings are in the order of 4-15-45 clocks for local L1, L2, L3 hits. For a typical 2.5GHz freq, that's a min-max of 1.6ns-18ns. That's about 5-6 orders of magnitude *less* than a typical timer tick.

Comment: Thanks! As for unstable, i was afraid of cases where some newly introduced delay will make other dependent components timed-out while they aren't expecting this

Answer (score 0):

Bad.

An OS does a lot of things on a timer interrupt. It sounds like what you are proposing to add is insignificant. But I still wouldn't recommend adding it to the timer interrupt handler itself. Interrupt handlers are tricky business.

You should use the systems in place in the kernel to schedule your task to run. (Sorry I can't be more specific, but if you are seriously considering changing a fundamental interrupt handler, then you should have no trouble figuring it out.)